# Pluralization rule for some compound terms in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to create a pluralization rule for some terms that aren't correctly pluralized. I'll place it on my **inflections.rb** file.

The terms are some compound ones that I may pluralize the first word, instead of the second, but, in my case, I don't have the option to apply the pluralize function on the first term only. For example:

`'base of knowledge'.pluralize` should return `'bases of knowledge'` instead of `'base of knowledges'`

I tried a regexp like this one `/\sof\s/` to find the  `of`  part on the string, but could't write a rule to inflect correctly.

> inflect.plural(???, ???)

Obs: I'm not looking for a linguistic workaround, like *'knowledge base'*. The example is merely illustrative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a way to inflect the compound term by adding this rule:

> inflect.plural(/(^\w+)\s(of\s\w+)/i, '\1s \2')

Then I got:

> 'base of knowledge'.pluralize -> 'bases of knowledge'

as expected

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

1. Create a file called: `config/initializers/inflections.rb`
2. Simple non-dynamic example:

   ```
   ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
     inflect.irregular 'base of knowledge', 'bases of knowledge'
   end
   ```

   This just requires you to specify each irregular plural phrase instead of a word. As long you call the pluralize method, it will find it.

Edit:

If you just want one method to handle all these types of changes. You could define an `irregular_pluralize` method that accepts the same inputs as pluralize or that accepts 3 objects.

```
def irregular_pluralize(count, string)
  if count > 1
    split_string = string.split(" ")
    size = split_string.size
    first = split_string.first
    first.pluralize + " " + split_string.last(size - 1).join(" ")
  else
    string
  end
end
```

Comment: I already have some irregular inflections on my app, but for this case in particular I need a general rule. The example is just one of the cases of the something_of_something rule. I also translated my problem to make it better for SO, because the original is similar but is in portuguese.

Comment: Anyway, if there isn't a better generalized way, I'll use your idea! thanks

Comment: I just created a quick method that you can use. I didn't edit pluralize directly, but you can call this the same way as pluralize in your code. This would go in application helper.

Comment: I think your method irregular_pluralize could be just string.gsub(/(^\w+)\s/, "\\1s "). I think this substitution with backreference may be the answer. This just needs to be put in a pluralization rule somehow. I can't try it out on my code right now, but I'll do try later.